# Microsoft Graph 503 service unavailable

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, postman, http-status-code-503

I try to use the Microsoft graph api with Postman app,
When i execute this query :

[image: query]

the api works and return me the good response :

[image: response]

But when I try to execute the query to have my to do lists I have a 503 error :
[image: query error 503]

Is anyone knows how to resolve it ?

Here's my authorized api :

[image: authorized api]

Comment: Can you check what are the permissions in access token at https://jwt.ms? Also try to check logging into the [graph explorer](https://aka.ms/ge)

Comment: Did you specify the token in postman?

Comment: The permissions are : "scp": "Mail.Read User.Read User.Read.All profile openid email",
It's weird because in Azur I also have Tasks.ReadWrite permissions

Comment: Yes I specified the token

Comment: Try adding Tasks.ReadWrite permission and test it. Check if you added Delegated permission or application permission.

Comment: I add a screen of my app permissions in Azure ans there is the Tasks.ReadWrite but this permission isn't in the token

Comment: Are you using MSA account or Work account? Try getting the token once again and see if it works.

Comment: I think this is a work account I use it with the student offer.
I will retry

Comment: I just retry, it's the same can it be because iI put this value in my scope : https://graph.microsoft.com/.default ?

Comment: Try adding Group.ReadWrite.All permission and check if it works. Similar issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65584822/to-do-api-the-service-is-not-available

Comment: I add it but the issue is the same. The token doesn't take all permissions in the scope : "scp": "Mail.Read User.Read User.Read.All profile openid email"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "TaskReadWrite" permission has not been added successfully , as we can see, there is no status Shown on screenshot you provided, could you please retry and add the "TaskReadWrite" delegated permission.

reference docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/todo-list-lists?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions.
[image]